# Passing a variable using hidden input

Tags: php

I've just started to learn php and I decided to work on a simple ticket system. I've managed to show a list of tickets and then when user clicks on the ticket id I can show the ticket details passing the ticket id variable to the url.

Now, to update the ticket I've created a new form with `action="ctrl_client_edit_ticket.php" method="post"` so in this file I can execute the database query to update the ticket.

The problem is that I have to use `_POST` to assign the ticket id to a new variable. So I thought maybe I could create a hidden field in the form `<input type="hidden" name="ticketid" value="<?php echo $ticket_id ?>">`

It is working but I don't really know if this is the best and safer method to do this operation.

Many thanks

This is the code.

**This is the file client_view_ticket.php where i show to the user all the tickets.**

```
<?php  

    $view_ticket_query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT ticket_id, ticket_subject, ticket_status, ticket_time_stamp FROM user_tickets WHERE ticket_user_id= ? "); 

    $view_ticket_query -> bind_param("i", $userid);
    $view_ticket_query -> execute();
    $view_ticket_query -> bind_result($ticket_id, $ticket_subject, $ticket_status, $ticket_time_stamp);


    while($view_ticket_query -> fetch())
    {  
        // set ticket's colors
        if ($ticket_status == "Aperto"){
            $tcolor = "<span class='label label-lg label-success'>";
        }else if ($ticket_status == "Chiuso"){
            $tcolor = "<span class='label label-lg label-danger'>";
        }else if ($ticket_status == "In Lavorazione"){
            $tcolor = "<span class='label label-lg label-info'>";
        }

        echo '
        <tr>
            <td><a href="client_edit_ticket.php?id='.$ticket_id.'"> '.$ticket_id.'</a></td>
            <td><a href="client_edit_ticket.php?id='.$ticket_id.'"> '.$ticket_subject.'</a></td>

            <td>'.$ticket_time_stamp.'</td>
             <td>'.$tcolor.'' .$ticket_status. '</span></td>
        </tr>

        ';
    }

    $view_ticket_query -> close();   
?>
```

**This is the file client_edit_ticket.php**

```
<?php
// Prelevo l'id del ticket dall'url e lo passo ad una variabile
$ticket_id = $_GET['id'];


// Query al database per prendere i dati del ticket
$view_ticket = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT ticket_subject, ticket_body, ticket_user_first, ticket_user_last, ticket_user_email, ticket_time_stamp, ticket_status, ticket_priority FROM user_tickets WHERE ticket_id= ? "); 

$view_ticket -> bind_param("i", $ticket_id);
$view_ticket -> execute();
$view_ticket -> bind_result($ticket_subject, $ticket_message, $ticket_user_first, $ticket_user_last, $ticket_user_email, $ticket_created_time, $ticket_status, $ticket_priority);
$view_ticket -> fetch();
$view_ticket -> close();

// Coverto la data di creazione del ticket in un formato europeo
$new_ticket_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($ticket_created_time));


?>
 <form class="form-group" action="controllers/ctrl_client_edit_ticket.php" method="post">

   <!--  hidden input for ticket id -->
    <input type="hidden" name="ticketid" value="<?php echo $ticket_id ?>">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h3>
                            <i class="icon-action-redo"></i> Messaggio di risposta</h3>
                        <textarea class="ticket-reply-msg" row="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h3 class="ticket-margin">
                            <i class="icon-info"></i> Aggiorna Priorità</h3>
                        <select class="ticket-status" name="ticketpriority">
                            <option value="Bassa" selected>Bassa</option>
                            <option value="Media">Media</option>
                            <option value="Alta">Alta</option>
                            <option value="Urgente">Urgente</option>
                            <option value="Critica">Critica</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-square uppercase bold green" type="submit">Aggiorna</button>
    </form>
```

**This is the file ctrl_client_edit_ticket.php**

```
$ticket_id = $_POST['ticketid'];
$ticket_priority = check_input($_POST['ticketpriority']);

if ($ticket_update_query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE user_tickets SET ticket_priority= ? WHERE ticket_id= ? ")) { 

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ticket_update_query, 'si', $ticket_priority, $ticket_id);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($ticket_update_query);

    echo "ticket aggiornato";


} else{

    echo "ticket non aggiornato";
}       

?>
```

Comment: yeah share some more code

Comment: Share the real code, or this question is going to get closed pretty quickly

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site, and welcome to the joys of web programming! I'm not sure this question as it stands now is a great fit for this site, because it's asking for quite broad opinions on the best way to approach a particular task. I'd recommend having a look through the introduction pages in the [help] to get an idea of what kind of question this site is aimed at.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the nice comments. I've just started programming with php and it is really great fun :) this website is amazing i found a lot of informations.

Answer (score -1):

This is a fairly common pattern when submitting forms to update existing data. Remember than an ID is just a unique identifier so the system knows how to find single entities.

Another option is to include the ID of the item in the route URL of the page (eg `/ticket/{$ticketId}` for router-based systems like Laravel, or `/ticket?id={$ticketId}`), but this only makes sense when the purpose of that page is to manage that particular data.

As @IMSoP commented, this question (as posed) may be better suited to one of the other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score -1):

Its not the safest way because `POST` data can be easily intercepted and changed on the fly, but you should implement security measures at the `client_edit_ticket.php` and make sure that the user has permission to edit the ticket, if a user tries to change the hidden input value to another ticket his request should be blocked.